# Use results from first WITH AS statement in second AS statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres 9.5

How can I use the WITH statement in a manner where I can use the results from the first WITH AS? Right now I am getting:

```
psql:query.sh:7: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "foo2"
LINE 6: ...INTO copy_on_write(id, images, posted_by) VALUES (foo2.id, f...
```

---

```
WITH foo1 AS (SELECT listings.id, listings.images, listings.posted_by
  FROM listings WHERE listings.posted_by = 10209280753550922::text
  AND listings.id = 5),
foo2 AS (SELECT foo1.id, foo1.images, users.internal_id FROM foo1
 JOIN users ON users.id = foo1.posted_by)
INSERT INTO copy_on_write(id, images, posted_by) VALUES (foo2.id, foo2.images, foo2.internal_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `INSERT . . . SELECT`, not `INSERT . . . VALUES`:

```
WITH foo1 AS (
      SELECT l.id, l.images, l.posted_by
      FROM listings l
      WHERE l.posted_by = 10209280753550922::text AND l.id = 5
     ),
     foo2 AS (
      SELECT foo1.id, foo1.images, u.internal_id
      FROM foo1 JOIN
           users u
           ON u.id = foo1.posted_by
     )
INSERT INTO copy_on_write(id, images, posted_by)
    SELECT foo2.id, foo2.images, foo2.internal_id
    FROM foo2;
```